# Error inflating class android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewgroup

I am trying to write a custom view for checkboxPreferences. I have:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
 android:key="@string/pref_acceptableads"
 android:summaryOff="@string/pref_acceptableads_summary_off"
 android:summaryOn="@string/pref_acceptableads_summary_on"
 android:title="@string/pref_acceptableads_title"
 android:widgetLayout="@layout/helpfulcheckbox_layout" />
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ViewGroup>
```

Problem is with my viewgroup. I receive an exception:

> 03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): Process:
>   org.adblockplus.android, PID: 12286 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class android.view.ViewGroup 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:489) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:460) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>   03-11 13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   can't instantiate class android.view.ViewGroup 03-11 13:49:11.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12286):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 03-11
>   13:49:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    ... 51 more

Can you give me a hit what is going on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) is an abstract class.

Use another layout as [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) or [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

In LogCat you have:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12286): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.view.ViewGroup
```

Comment: I do not know. When I try to accept your answer just after flag it up I see a pop up "You can accept this answer in 10 minutes" and counting down ;) Anyway: accepted. Thanks again - good lesson of basics :)